# Why does Android TalkBack not select this Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextField if I have specfic text as the placeholder?

Tags: android, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, selection

I'm testing my application for accessibility compatibility using TalkBack. However, certain OutlinedTextFields are being skipped and are unselectable even by clicking if TalkBack is enabled. I created a sample app using the latest versions of Kotlin/Gradle/Compose to make sure it wasn't something to do with my project setup.

Changing the "placeholder" text to certain values allows TalkBack selection, and other values make it unselectable (e.g. "MM/DD/YYYY" makes TalkBack skip the field, but "Hello World" allows TalkBack to select the field).

Code is as follows:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PlaygroundTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = remember{mutableStateOf("")}.value,
                        onValueChange = {

                        },
                        label = {
                            Text(text = "Date of Birth")
                        },
                        placeholder = {
                            Text(text = "MM/DD/YYYY") //TalkBack won't select the field with this placeholder

//                          Text(text = "Hello World") //TalkBack WILL select the field with this placeholder
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}
```

Here are the dependencies I'm using:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.0-alpha01'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.playground"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

Are there certain strings or characters that are forbidden by TalkBack?

Comment: Facing the same issue, any luck?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem... I ran some test (with androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.0-beta03):

- OutlinedTextField empty.❌
- OutlinedTextField with placeholder.✅
- OutlinedTextField with placeholder and label.❌
- OutlinedTextField with label.✅
- TextField empty.❌
- TextField with placeholder.✅
- TextField with placeholder and label.✅
- TextField with label.✅

There is a difference of behavior between `TextField` and `OutlinedTextField` when we put a `placeholder` and a `label`. There are some similar issues on Google's issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246740235), [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242439166) or [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242389347).

I found no others solutions than using only `label` with an `OutlinedTextField`, as accessibility is not optional for us. I made a new issue on [Google's tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/251162419) with the following sample I made, and the result:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(all = 16.dp)
        .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState()),
) {
    // OutlinedTextField empty.❌
    Text(text = "OutlinedTextField empty")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 4.dp))
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))

    // OutlinedTextField with placeholder.✅
    Text(text = "OutlinedTextField with placeholder")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 4.dp))
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "",
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Placeholder") },
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))

    // OutlinedTextField with placeholder and label.❌
    Text(text = "OutlinedTextField with placeholder and label")
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "",
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Placeholder") },
        label = { Text(text = "Label") },
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))

    // OutlinedTextField with label.✅
    Text(text = "OutlinedTextField with label")
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "",
        label = { Text(text = "Label") },
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))

    // TextField empty.❌
    Text(text = "TextField empty")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 4.dp))
    TextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))

    // TextField with placeholder.✅
    Text(text = "TextField with Placeholder")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 4.dp))
    TextField(
        value = "",
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Placeholder") },
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))


    // TextField with placeholder and label.✅
    Text(text = "TextField with Placeholder and label")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 4.dp))
    TextField(
        value = "",
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Placeholder") },
        label = { Text(text = "Label") },
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))

    // TextField with label.✅
    Text(text = "TextField with label")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 4.dp))
    TextField(
        value = "",
        label = { Text(text = "Label") },
        onValueChange = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(height = 12.dp))
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

As @BerHug notes, there seems to be a bug. In order to make it read something out you can add a content description by adding a semantics modifier:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = modifier.semantics { 
        contentDescription = "this is a text entry box" 
    }, 
) {}
```

This will also cause the screen reader to add the additional instructions on how to activate the text entry field when it reads it out.

There's some useful additional information in these links:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility

https://bryanherbst.com/2020/11/03/compose-semantics-talkback/